# ExtJS: Rest Proxy Post Data Failure

Tags: rest, extjs, proxy

Hy,
I've a Problem by sending data via ExtJs Rest Proxy. When I POST Data I get the Exception

in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientIdProperty' of undefined

in Firefox: TypeError: clientRecords[0] is undefined

My Store

```
Ext.define('Test.store.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Test.model.test',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'Test',
        model: 'Test.model.test',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: '/resources/php/test.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

My Model

```
Ext.define('Test.model.test', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Field'
],

fields: [
    {
        name: 'Test'
    }
]
```

Is there a standard answer from Server?

I hope some one can Help me
Thx for Help

Comment: Assign a root property for your reader

Answer (score 0):

In your reader config, provide a 'root' property.

In ext 4.x it'll be like

```
reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'root'
    }
```

And in Ext 5.x, it'll be

```
reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'root'
    }
```

Here's what API doc says -

> [rootProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-rootProperty) : String The name of the property which contains the data
>   items corresponding to the Model(s) for which this Reader is
>   configured. For JSON reader it's a property name (or a dot-separated
>   list of property names if the root is nested). For XML reader it's a
>   CSS selector. For Array reader the root is not applicable since the
>   data is assumed to be a single-level array of arrays.
>
> By default the natural root of the data will be used: the root JSON
>   array, the root XML element, or the array.
>
> The data packet value for this property should be an empty array to
>   clear the data or show no data.
>
> Defaults to: ''

For example, if the JSON response from the server is

```
{
  "data": {
    "Test": "TEST"
  },
  "someOtherField": "Some Value"
}
```

then, your rootProperty/ root will become -

```
rootProperty: 'data'
```

- Since data corresponds to your model